# Undefined or null variable in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In these example I am ruining a function with conditions;

```
function validPrice(price)
{
    if(price=="" || price==0 || price==null || price==undefined )
    { 
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something different
    }
}
var priceNew = $("li#listedProd").attr("price"); 

validPrice(priceNew);
```

My question is what are the different in these condition `price=="" || price==0 || price==null || price==undefined`

Comment: you can replace all of that by `!price`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever first wrote that code was either

a) Being very defensive against future use.
b) Didn't understand how `attr` works.

The method `attr` (or the underlying call of `getAttribute` will return either

- A string value, of the attribute is found
- `null`, if it is not.

Importantly, should there have been a `0` value, it would be a *string* `0`, <strike>and thus not caught in the test below</strike> -- caught against the `price == 0` test because the system would have automatically converted it to a number as part of the `==` compare.

```
if(price=="" || price==0 || price==null || price==undefined )
```

And, due to the way that conversions work internally, those tests don't work as intended.  `==` and `===` are different.  It should be:

```
if(price === "" || price === 0 || price === null || price === undefined )
```

All of which can easily be reduced to simply "price" due how how [coercion to boolean work](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/):

```
if (!price)
```

Or, if you want to catch `"0"` values

```
if (!price || +price === 0)
```

(the +price forces price to be a number, so we catch `0` `0.00` and other variations.)

Comment: Thank you i think this is great digestive answer

Comment: It should be coercion to boolean, not cohesion

Comment: @Simlofi: The `price == null` and `price == undefined` are performing identical tests. Don't do `price === null || price === undefined` either because it's unnecessarily verbose. Just do one of the first two when the situation calls for it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your conditional statement term-by-term:

```
price == ""
```

This is `true` if price is the empty string, and `false` otherwise.

```
price == 0
```

This is `true` if price is the integer `0`, the string `"0"`, or the empty string, and `false` otherwise. You should change this comparison to `price === 0` if you want to catch when `price` is the integer `0`.

```
price == null
```

This is `true` if price is passed to your function and is of the type `null`, and false otherwise.

```
price == undefined
```

Note: You should probably make this comparison via `price === undefined` to see that `price` is both `undefined` and has the type `undefined`.

This is `true` if price is not passed to your function, or if price is otherwise `undefined`, and `false` otherwise.

I would recommend just making the entire conditional statement `!price`:

```
function validPrice(price) {
    if (!price) { 
        //do something
    }
    else {
        // do something different
    }
};

var priceNew = $("li#listedProd").attr("price"); 

validPrice(priceNew);
```

Comment: _price == 0 - This is true if price is the integer 0, and false otherwise._ Not exactly. The use of `==` here would return true even if the `price` is a `string` equals `"0"`. To make sure the variable type is considered, use `===` instead.

Comment: Noted. I've added an edit to my answer above clarifying this point.

Comment: ```price == 0``` also returns true if price is ```""```, ```false``` and some other things. ```price=="" || price==0``` is _almost_ redundant and so is ```price==null || price==undefined```.

Comment: so in coding you mean  var price == "" and price ==0 are not the same thing

Comment: Great comments, I've updated my answer with all of these clarifications. Thanks @Volune.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT added definitions**

JavaScript has 2 operators that test for equality (and conversely 2 operators that test for inequality.)

- A ***strict equality*** comparison (e.g., ===) is only true if the operands are of the *same* type **AND** if the object is actually the same object, or the primitives have the same value (e.g., 0 === 0, and 'a' === 'a' are both true).  *Note there is a slight exception to this rule for NaN (see below)
- An ***abstract equality*** comparison (e.g. ==) converts the operands to the same Type (if they aren't already) before making a ***strict equality*** comparison.  If however one of the operands is `null` or `undefined`, the comparison is true if and only if the other operand is either `null` or `undefined`.

So in short the `==` equality operator is considered by many to be unsafe. To see the difference  checkout http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

For instance `'' ==`: `0, '', [], false, [[]]`

And `0 ==`: `false, 0, '0', '', [], [[]], [0]`

While `null ==`: `null, undefined`

And finally `undefined ==`: `null, undefined`

It is better to use strict equal `===` or just test for a falsey value (`'', 0, undefined, null, false`)

`if (!price) { //do something }`

### Below I have provided more details about strict vs abstract equality comparison

details came from ECMA-262, Edition 5 11.9.1
**Summary of strict equality algorithm**

```
1. If typeof(x) is different from typeof(y), return false.
2. If typeof(x) is undefined, return true.
3. If x is null, return true.
4. If typeof(x) is number, then
    a. If x is NaN, return false.
    b. If y is NaN, return false.
    c. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
    d. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
    e. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
    f. Return false.
5. If typeof(x) is string, then
    a. If x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in
corresponding positions), return true.
    b. Else, return false.
6. If typeof(x) is boolean, then
    a. If x and y are both true or both false, return true.
    b. Else, return false.
7. If x and y are the same Object value, return true.
8. Return false.
```

And ... details came from  ECMA-262, Edition 5 11.9.1
**Summary of Abstract Equality Algorithm**

```
1. If typeof(x) is the same as typeof(y), then
    return the result of performing strict equality comparison algorithm x === y.
2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
4. If typeof(x) is number and typeof(y) is string,
    return the result of the comparison x == Number(y).
5. If typeof(x) is string and typeof(y) is number,
    return the result of the comparison Number(x) == y.
6. If typeof(x) is boolean, return the result of the comparison Number(x) == y.
7. If typeof(y) is boolean, return the result of the comparison x == Number(y).
8. If typeof(x) is either string or number and typeof(y) is object,
    return the result of the comparison x == [[ToPrimitive]](y).
9. If typeof(x) is object and typeof(y) is either string or number,
    return the result of the comparison [[ToPrimitive]](x) == y.
10. Return false.

[[ToPrimitive]] is an internal function call
```

Bullets 8 and 9 basically mean that objects are converted like object.valueOf().toString() so:

`{} == '[Object object]'
{ hi: 'hi'} == '[Object object]'
{ valueOf: function(){ return 0; }} == 0
{ toString: function(){ return 'hi'; }} == 'hi'
{ valueOf: function(){ return 0; }, toString: function(){ return 'hi'; }} == 0`

[Full ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9)

Comment: @user2864740 you downvoted seconds after i posted, while i was still editing it